# Full screen Windows games on dual monitor doesn't work

Tags: wine, games, fullscreen

When using games in full screen, they don't set the right resolution, and they show a little across both monitors.

Example 1: Rust, through Steam. It works for a second, then the resolution is messed up and the clicking and hovering position doesn't match the cursor.

[image]

Example 2: Diablo IV running in Bottles launcher: when I choose full screen mode, it only shows part of the screen, and again the cursor doesn't match the real position.

[image]

Counterexample: Dota 2. Dota runs natively in  Linux and it works pretty well here. The second screen is messed up, but the game works well in full screen.

Screen settings, showing the Samsung on the right is set as the primary display:

[image]

Please let me know if there's anything I can try to fix this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Wayland** greatly improves full-screen behaviour with dual monitors. Wayland can be enabled on the login screen in the bottom right corner.

Full screen works great in both example games above. The only problem is that the game resolution is limited to lower than the native resolution when using display scaling (e.g. 150%).

[I haven't got a good feel for whether the display latency is okay yet, will update answer if it's really bad.]